# Visual C++ 2010 can't find .NET and can't untarget it

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I've been using VS 2005 for quite some time and have become very used to it.
Lately, I got VS 2010 from msdnaa and tried converting a project and failed. However, after making a new one, including the old files, the program compiled and worked flawlessly.

The next time I opened the project, it wanted .NET, which I have, but it can't find. It might be because I have the "Program Files" folder set to drive D:\ via the Registry, but I symlinked microsoft.net, msbuild, etc. which it might need.

But why does it need .NET anyway? I can only change the target version, not untarget it, but when I do, it needs VS 2008. I have been making c++ programs without .NET just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab in the dark... perhaps you have turned on **Common Language Runtime Support** in the General Tab of the project? You should compile without such support.

Answer (score 0):

**You've inadvertently created a [C++/CLI application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), which allows you to write C++ code in an application targeting the .NET Framework.**

To remove support on the Common Language Runtime, thus removing the insisted dependency on the .NET Framework, follow these steps:

1. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer, and click "Properties" on the drop-down menu.
2. Make sure that you're viewing the "General" tab under the "Configuration Properties" heading.
3. Find the box labeled "Common Language Runtime Support" under the "Project Defaults" category in the grid on the right.
4. Set that property to "No Common Language Runtime Support".
5. Click OK.

[image: Removing CLI support from C++ application]

Your project may or may not compile after doing this if you've used classes that are provided by the .NET Framework in your source code. Attempt a build, and then use the Error List to fix any problems that may have cropped up.

Comment: Well, that property was as it should have been. "No Common Language Runtime Support"

Comment: @Murka: Have you checked that *all* projects have this set correctly? If you have multiple libraries that make up your code base, that could explain how this went undetected.

Comment: I only have one small project. It includes some regular stuff i've always used and opengl libraries.